# BLE OTA firmware loading "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to do an Over The Air firmware update for the Bluegiga BLE121LR Bluetooth module.

I'm getting all the way to the characteristic write (it's supposed to be a write_no_repsonse type) and that's where it just hangs up and seems to kick itself out of the while loop and I get the "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." warning in my logcat output.

I'm executing the following code in onResume after making sure my radio connection is established.  The OTA file is in the assets folder and seems to load into the byte array properly.

I'm very much a novice and I'm sure there's a threading convention or something that I'm missing here.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

```
try {
                InputStream dis;
                try {
                    dis = getAssets().open("BLE121LR_OTA.ota");
                    byte[] fileData1 = new byte[dis.available()];

                    try {
                        this.wait(200);
                        dis.read(fileData1);
                        int length = fileData1.length;
                        Log.i(TAG, "Length of file: " + length);
                        int i = 0;

                        if (mService != null) {
                            otaDataChar = mService.getCharacteristic(IOPENER_OTA_DATA);
                            otaControlChar = mService.getCharacteristic(IOPENER_OTA_CONTROL);

                            while (i < length) {

                                byte[] byte16 = new byte[16];
                                System.arraycopy(fileData1, i, byte16, 0, 16);
                                Log.e(TAG, "byte16" + getHexString(byte16));
                                otaDataChar.setValue(getHexString(byte16));
                                otaDataChar.setWriteType(4);
                                mConnectedGatt.writeCharacteristic(otaDataChar);
                                Log.e(TAG, "CHAR WRITE");
                                i = i + 16;
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Mservice fucked up.");
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "BEGIN FLASH REBOOT");
                        // otaControlChar.setValue("3");
                        // mConnectedGatt.writeCharacteristic(otaControlChar);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        dis.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

And it had nothing to do with threading...I was trying to operate on a null.